# Using ampersand-sync with Node's request library

Tags: node.js, ampersand.js

I was working on writing a wrapper for an API to run some tests in Node, and realized this would be much simpler if I could abstract these as Backbone/Ampersand models and leverage the CRUD semantics of the library.

Glancing around the [ampersand-sync](https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-sync) project I noticed a file that overloaded `xhr` with `request`. I guess my question is how do I take advantage of this so that I may use the awesome force of Ampersand models when writing wrappers to test my APIs in a Node.js context? (That is not in the browser.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Future proof answer: just use it in node.

You looked at a major change that has just been merged. We're close to a major version bump and a release.

All you have to do is wait for the 4.0 to get released and used as dependency in state and/or model. I'm close to releasing sync@4.0 so it's not a long wait.

Once it's there, you just use ampersand-sync in nodejs and it works.
You can try installing from github. The release is a breaking change, but it's mostly in error response formats :)

Comment: Boom! Thanks, here's your bonus points. I'm pretty excited about this. Total game changer when it comes to wrapping APIs for test purposes/crawling.